# Permission denied while updating user doc in a batch write in Firestore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Here is the exception I get:

> W/Firestore(22209): (24.9.1) [WriteStream]: (e05714f) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}.

My code is as follows:

```dart
  /// Marks user as deleted as long as all his ads
  Future<void> storeMarkAsDeletedAsLongAsAllHisAds() async {
    final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final writeBatch = fs.batch();

    // Get user from the (current) ID
    final user = await fs.collection("users").doc(id).get();

    // Mark user as deleted
    writeBatch.update(user.reference, {
      "deleted": true,
    });


    return writeBatch.commit();
  }
```

And my ruled are as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
         
    // === Get the user using uid
    function getUser() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
    }
      
    match /users/{uid}/{document=**} {
       allow read: if true; 
       allow create, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == uid;  
    }
```

What's wrong?

Comment: When I run into a problem like this, the first thing I do is have my code check whether it meets the requirements of my rules. So: wrap `storeMarkAsDeletedAsLongAsAllHisAds` in `if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null)` and see if that chances things.

Comment: Oh my! That’s so true! I feel stupid for having deleted the user before his documents! So everything’s ok now. Write down the answer so that I can accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nothing to feel stupid about, it happens to all of us regularly. Good to hear that was the problem indeed. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run into a problem like this, the first thing I do is have my code check whether it meets the requirements of my rules. So: wrap `storeMarkAsDeletedAsLongAsAllHisAds` in a condition like:

```
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null)
```

And see if that chances things.